# Forms authentication not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, forms-authentication, authorization

I am trying to use Forms Authentication for the first time. This is what I have in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="Login" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30" path="/">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

The website I am working on doesn't actually need any authentication because the page should be accessible without logging in. So that's why I'm allowing all users. I am very new to this so there's probably something obvious I'm doing wrong, but all pages seem to redirect to Login.aspx, even though I'm allowing all users.

All help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
As one answer directed, I changed the code to the below (changed * to ?) but I still have the same problem:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 2):

Asterisk stands for *any authenticated* user which does not include anonymous users. Use question to allow anonymous users:

```
<allow users="?" />
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've changed the * to ? but I still have the same thing happening.

Comment: This is not light reading but a good start to help you out. I am using MVC these days and will never go back to webforms. LINK:http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs

Comment: You should have something in your web.config that looks like this: <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30"
           name=".ASPXAUTH" 
           path="/"
           requireSSL="false"
           slidingExpiration="true"
           defaultUrl="default.aspx"
           cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>

Comment: It would not let me post that in the answer box

Comment: @Leah, could you post your `web.config` file? Also, do you use IIS or Cassini development web server?

Comment: @Leah, also, there should be a `deny` statement to deny anything. Your initial configuration should allow everyone anyways. So there's something else. What happens if you remove `authentication` section?

Answer (score 0):

I came at this page having the same problem, and see that 5 years later this has never been properly answered.. You needed to specify the following in web.config:

```
 <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
     <allow users="*" />
 </authorization>
```

Meaning that you deny access to all anonymous users, and allowing access to all authenticated users.